# Sine and Cosine Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question, education, mnemonic

The derivatives of:

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$$
>   $$\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x)=-\sin(x)$$

I currently trying to teach a friend of mine calculus, because he does not know it yet.  He keeps forgetting how to take the derivatives of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.  Is there a simple way, or trick to remember the derivatives of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$?

Comment: What exactly do you find difficult in remembering these relations?

Comment: You should read this: http://daylateanddollarshort.com/mathdocs/Calculus-free-Derivatives-of-Sine-and-Cosine.pdf

(WARNING: it is a bit hand-wavy)

Comment: Does your friend know what sine and cosine look like?  If he does, then remembering which one gets the negative sine should be straightforward.

Comment: Show your friend a derivation of the derivatives using the limit definition of derivative. I think may be this will help him memorize it. Moreover, if he ever forgot it, he can re-derive it himself.

Comment: Thanks for everybody contributing to the question! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not that I know of.  Practice, practice, and then more practice.  That's how I've remembered them since 2001.  (Teaching also helps.)

Only slightly related to your question, here's a nice little factoid:

> \begin{alignat}{3}
>   \frac d{dx} \sin x &= \cos x & \qquad\qquad \frac d{dx} \cos x &= -\sin x\\[0.3cm]
>   \frac d{dx} \sec x &= \sec x \tan x & \frac d{dx} \csc x &= -\csc x \cot x\\[0.3cm]
>   \frac d{dx} \tan x &= \sec^2 x & \frac d{dx} \cot x &= -\csc^2 x\\[0.3cm]
> \end{alignat}

The derivatives of all the functions beginning with "co" have minus signs on them.  The others do not.

Comment: That is a cool observation.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use unit circle (for almost everything in trigonometry)

A simple way to memorize these formula is concentration on increasing & decreasing in their plots.

I highly recommend using a good applet. Visualizing  is  very helpful

Try these to find a suitable applet. I suggest [this](https://www.geogebra.org/search/perform/search/unit%20circle%20/materials/) one for example.

Comment: How does the unit circle help with derivatives?

Comment: @tilper I mean you could think about as cosine is increasing, sine is decreasing.  Since as cosine approaches 1, sine approaches zero.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU it will be very useful that the student see an increasing angle with the plot of it's sine & cosine and the velocity of changes in plots. you can find some interesting applets in Geogebra

Comment: @BD. Geogebra is awesome and that sounds like a plan.

Answer (score 4):

If you've memorized the *graphs* of sine and cosine, and know that the derivatives are also some form of sine and cosine, then use the fact that the derivative at any point is the *slope* of the graph at that point.

For example, the slope of the sine function at $x=0$ is $1$, and it falls to zero at $x=\pi/2$. This should remind you of the cosine function. Similarly the slope of the cosine function at $x=0$ is zero, and it decreases to $-1$ at $x=\pi/2$, leading to the negative of the sine function. This geometric interpretation should get you the signs right as well as the form of the function.

Answer (score 3):

One way you can remember them that is fairly easy, so long as you remember the shapes of their graphs, is to recognize that the slope of $\sin x$ at $0$ is positive (it looks like it's $1$), then tends to $0$ at $\pi/2$, then becomes negative (it looks like it's $-1$) at $\pi$, then becomes $0$ again at $3\pi/2$ and finally ends up positive at $2\pi$. If you "connect the dots", you will see that the graph is that of $\cos x$. A similar procedure applies for remembering the derivative of $\cos x$.

Answer (score 3):

First we should remember that these two functions are derivative one for other, except the sign. Now we want to determine the sign.
The derivative in a point is "how fast does the function rise". $\sin(x)$ is rising at $x=0$ so $(\sin(x))'$ must be positive at $x=0$. OK, $\cos(x)$ is suitable. The same way for $\cos(x)$: it doesn't change near $0$, then decreases. So $(\cos(x))'$ must be null at $x=0$, then negative. $-\sin(x)$ is suitable.

Of course it is not a way to find the derivative, just to remember.

Answer (score 3):

Using complex numbers:

$$\cos x+i\sin x=e^{ix}$$

then

$$\cos'x+i\sin'x=(e^{ix})'=ie^{ix}=-\sin x+i\cos x.$$

By this method you can obtain the derivatives for higher orders

$$\cos''x+i\sin''x=i^2e^{ix}=-\cos x-i\sin x,$$
$$\cos'''x+i\sin'''x=i^3e^{ix}=\sin x-i\cos x,$$
 and so on.

---

Alternatively, if you give the angle $x$ a small increment, the corresponding point on the trigonometric circle will move in the direction of the tangent to the circle, which is orthogonal to the position vector.

$$(\cos x,\sin x)\to(-\sin x, \cos x).$$

[image]